# nodejs server not receiving any parameters from POST request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax, express

server.js:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    loggedIn = {};

    app.use('/',express.static('www')); // static files

    app.listen(8080, function () {
      console.log('Port 8080!');
    });

    app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
        if (typeof req.param('user') != 'undefined') {
            user = req.param('user');
            res.status(200).send('Works');
        }
    });

    app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
            user = req.param('user');
            if (typeof users[user] != 'undefined') {
                return res.status(405).send('Access Forbidden');
            } else {
                   loggedIn[user] = "";
                   res.status(201).send('New User');
            }
        }
    });
```

client.js requests:

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/user",
        data: {"user" : user},
        dataType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            // success
        },
        error: function() {
            // error case
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/user",
        data: {"user" : user},
        dataType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            // success
        },
        error: function() {
            // error case
        }
    });
```

Even though the GET request works exactly as expected and passes the parameter here, for some reason, the post request doesn't. In firebug, I notice the POST request receives no parameters whatsoever (POST user) while GET request does (GET user?user=XYZ). I am really at a loss right now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell your express app to parse the request body

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

for express 4+

```
var express    = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

For reference goto https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req and look at the section titled **req.body**

Comment: I've tried this, but it gives me the error of middleware needing to be separately installed (I'm on express 4.0). However when I try installing it with "npm install --save body-parser", it doesn't let me (unknown system error -122, something to do with mkdir).

Comment: Finally managed to install body-parser, use req.body.<parameter> on all instances and it still isn't working. It's still hanging while having zero parameters on the POST. When I tried forcing ContentType to application/json in the request, it gave me 'Unexpected token u', meaning I was passing something undefined, even though the data being passed is clearly defined and, I've checked, all the respective values show up in the Firebug DOM section. I'm really lost.

Comment: server didn't receive my parameters